# Ctrl-Alt-T launches a different terminal than that from the launcher

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, terminator

If I launch terminal from the launcher

[image]

the following terminal appears:

[image]

But if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, a different one appears:

[image]

How to make the same one to appear?

Answer (score 11):

It seems you have **Terminator** (2nd pic) installed in your system (a different terminal emulator than the system one)

If you don't want to use it, a quick solution would be to uninstall it

```
sudo apt purge terminator
```

It'll restore your <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> shortcut back to the default one.

**Update:**
If you don't want to uninstall, follow these steps to restore your default terminal.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

you'll get this result.

[image: sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator]

This is the list of terminal emulators in your system. See for me default terminal is Terminator ( number 0 ) and it has a * next to it.

you have to choose which terminal you want to select as default.

Type the desired list number, Press enter, now it should restore your default terminal.

Comment: "a far superior terminal emulator than the system one" – such opinions are highly disputable. For one, Terminator has been unmaintained for about 2 years, thus lacks new features such as explicit hyperlinks, line/character spacing, or the setting for the new vs. old bold/bright color handling, all available in GNOME Terminal.

Comment: @egmont Removed. I find terminator to be more easy to work with / customize, so I added that line.

Comment: Is it possible to assign keystroke to the one terminal w/o uninstalling second one?

Comment: @Dims updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two different terminals installed, the default Ubuntu terminal and a terminal called Terminator.

You use two different launching methods, one with a shortcut key (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, and one using a desktop launcher in the toolbar.

It is up to you to configure your system such that an action you take does what you want. Thus, depending on the terminal emulator you want to use, change the launcher icon or change the command assigned to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. The details on how this is done dependent on the desktop environment you use. From the picture you posted< I guess that might be Unity.