# Tilix shortcuts problem

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Tilix has a shortcut "Ctrl+Alt+T" to open the terminal in Nautilius (In the currently opened directory), but ubuntu has the default same shortcut "Ctrl+Alt+T" to open the terminal from anywhere i.e Browser. Now the default shortcut always opens Tilix in the home directory, even if any directory is opened in Nautilius, simply the default shortcut is overriding the "Tilix Shortcut". How can I set the same shortcut for both actions? Means if I am in Nautilius the Tilix opens in the current directory and if I am using any other program i.e Browser, Tilix opens in the home directory by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not as such possible. The global key will always override. You will need to set a different global shortcut key.

Comment: Alright. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing
[Ctrl-Alt-T launches a different terminal than that from the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135970/ctrl-alt-t-launches-a-different-terminal-than-that-from-the-launcher)

Try this

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator
```

and select the option matching your Tilix executable.

Note the current selection, in case you want to come back to it at a later time - same command.