# How to change ctrl+alt+T back again?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, 22.04

I've always used ctrl+alt+T to open a new terminal window. Recently I installed cool-retro-term, and it hijacked that shortcut. I would like to keep cool-retro-term installed, but change the shortcut back to what is was before. Is that possible?

I have searched, if there should be other users with my problem, but all the results that pop up are more than ten years old, and the answers seem to involve configuration settings or programs that look somewhat outdated.

Comment: what does ctrl-alt-t do now? open cool-retro-term?

Comment: is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135970/ctrl-alt-t-launches-a-different-terminal-than-that-from-the-launcher) what you're looking for?

Comment: then the answer to the linked question should definitely apply

Comment: @Esther That's it! Thank you! I am somewhat surprised that Ubuntu doesn't come with a GUI tool for configuring keyboard shortcuts, or this isn't simply done by editing a text file, but this worked - thanks again!

Comment: That's because the issue isn't the "keyboard shortcut", and the keyboard shortcut wasn't modified. The issue is that ctrl-alt-t opens the "default terminal program," and cool-retro-term set itself as the default terminal emulator when you installed it. Therefore, ctrl-alt-t opened it, not the terminal emulator you were expecting. The instructions there just set it back the way it was before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ctrl-Alt-T launches a different terminal than that from the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135970/ctrl-alt-t-launches-a-different-terminal-than-that-from-the-launcher)